Facing issue while registering service of generic class after reading all class of same type using Reflection Assembly in c# dotnet
I have one generic class defined as below. While registering bean/service getting error that it didn't get register properly.
reflection code:
  var types = Assembly.Load("Come.Demo")
                 .GetTypes()
                 .Where(t => typeof(IDemo).IsAssignableFrom(t))
                 .ToList();

public class DemoService<TDemo> : BaseService
    where TDemo : class
{
    // Implementation
}

Using below code:
I have created dictionary of type : Dictinary<TypeName, Type> and iterating this dict to register the bean like below
if (type.IsGenericType)
{
   services.AddScoped(typeof(BaseService), type);
}

Error:
System.ArgumentException: 'Cannot instantiate implementation type 'Com.Demo.DemoService`1[TDemo]' for service type 'Com.Demo.DemoService.BaseService'.'
Need help to understand why it is not getting registered.Is there any other way to do this?

Looks like you are trying to register a generic type (DemoService) as a non-generic service (BaseService).
My suggestion is to create a new interface for DemoService and use it.
interface IDemo { }
interface IDemoService<TDemo> : IDemo { }
public abstract class BaseService : IDemo { }
public class DemoService<TDemo> : BaseService, IDemoService<TDemo> { }

Registration
foreach (var type in types)
{
    if (type.IsGenericType)
    {                   
        services.AddScoped(typeof(IDemoService<>), type);
    }
}
var sp = services.BuildServiceProvider();

var demoService1 = sp.GetService<IDemoService<string>>();
var demoService2 = sp.GetService<IDemoService<int>>();


I don't have any interface the my generic class is extending.
IDemoService. Still getting same error
